# WebApi, File exists but file not found, IIS always reads from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express" folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have a web API solution which has a folder containing the configuration files ([see image of Solution Explorer showing config files here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXNy1.png))

The path names in the code are:

```
public const string CONFIGFILEPATH = "VTS_Data\\Config.vts";
public const string BCSEQUENCEFILEPATH = "VTS_Data\\BCSequenceNumber.xml";
public const string OPCCONFIGFILEPATH = "VTS_Data\\OPCTagConfiguration.das";
```

The application always reads from the path `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"`.
If I place the VTS_Data folder manually in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"` this path, the app works fine.

But, how does it take configuration from the path that is actually meant to be?

Also, when it is hosted as IIS site, VTS_Data folders needs to be present in IISExpress folder.

I have tried using `(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.CONFIGFILEPATH))` when needed to read from the path. and when I debug, it refers to the actual physical path, but `File.Exists` returns false even if the file exists.

I have given full control to everyone and ensured that the files are not read-only.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show your code that uses `(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.CONFIGFILEPATH))` and `File.Exists`?

Answer (score 0):

when I created a variable   `var baseDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/VTS_Data")` and used
 `var OPCConfigurationFilePath = Path.Combine(baseDir , OPCTagConfiguration.das);`
it started working. Seems like previously it was already pointing to a folder, and searching for another folder with the same name inside.
ex. instead of pointing to folderName/abc.txt, it is pointing to folderName/folderName/abc.txt